# Facebook Graph API returning different pages for different access tokens

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I have been using the Graph API normally for the past two months, but suddenly something strange started happening.

I have the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=
{$access_token}&q=obama&type=page
```

What happens is that when I use the access token related to the account that I have been using for the past two months, it simply does not return the most popular pages related to this keyword. This is the return:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
     "id": "593850270658078",
     "name": "Obama - The Worst President",
     "category": "Public figure",
     "likes": 16133,
     "talking_about_count": 27276
  },
  {
     "id": "363569443676394",
     "name": "2016: Obama's America",
     "category": "Movie",
     "likes": 291045,
     "talking_about_count": 8406
  },
  {
     "id": "524144210948251",
     "name": "Obama Won! U MAD?",
     "category": "Comedian",
     "likes": 93222,
     "talking_about_count": 17931
  },
  {
     "id": "249903348378912",
     "name": "Obama Makes Me Puke",
     "category": "Just for fun",
     "likes": 85377,
     "talking_about_count": 232842
  },
  {
     "id": "215380238549857",
     "name": "ObamaWear",
     "category": "Clothing",
     "likes": 5771,
     "talking_about_count": 4
  },
  {
     "id": "434951966574117",
     "name": "Obamagump.com",
     "category": "Political organization",
     "likes": 2336,
     "talking_about_count": 686
  },
  {
     "id": "235805483212602",
     "name": "ObamaCalls",
     "category": "Website",
     "likes": 1849,
     "talking_about_count": 7
  },
  {
     "id": "475266032570062",
     "name": "Obama, stay away from SYRIA",
     "category": "Community",
     "likes": 712,
     "talking_about_count": 531
  }, ....
```

However, when I tried using the access token from a different Facebook account, it returned the results starting from the the most popular page, which was happening with the other account until today. This is the result:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
     "id": "6815841748",
     "name": "Barack Obama",
     "category": "Politician",
     "likes": 36654370,
     "talking_about_count": 563401
  },
  {
     "id": "22092775577",
     "name": "Michelle Obama",
     "category": "Public figure",
     "likes": 10006156,
     "talking_about_count": 122888
  },
  {
     "id": "250438165090859",
     "name": "Malia Obama.",
     "category": "Public figure",
     "likes": 439221,
     "talking_about_count": 78225
  },
  {
     "id": "325578590837480",
     "name": "Obamacare",
     "category": "Community",
     "likes": 515138,
     "talking_about_count": 23672
  },
  {
     "id": "424717587573142",
     "name": "Bardock Obama",
     "category": "Comedian",
     "likes": 151115,
     "talking_about_count": 55308
  },
  {
     "id": "593850270658078",
     "name": "Obama - The Worst President",
     "category": "Public figure",
     "likes": 16121,
     "talking_about_count": 21111
  },
  {
     "id": "363569443676394",
     "name": "2016: Obama's America",
     "category": "Movie",
     "likes": 291045,
     "talking_about_count": 8406
  },
  {
     "id": "296856040436954",
     "name": "Obama is the Worst President in US History",
     "category": "Community",
     "likes": 693421,
     "talking_about_count": 108681
  },
  {
     "id": "214488188596423",
     "name": "Impeach Obama",
     "category": "Cause",
     "likes": 98256,
     "talking_about_count": 25708
  }, ....
```

I noticed that the same happened with other keywords that I had been using very frequently.

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Everything that Facebook delivers gets rated based on the user’s likes, preferences, interests, etc. – so it is normal and intended for the API search to return different results based on “who” is actually performing the search. (Furthermore, pages might be restricted to certain demographics or the 21+ age range [alcohol related content] – of course the search has to reflect that as well.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, CBroe. What is strange is that I spent two months getting the correct results, and suddenly, I am only getting pages "less important" now. With other account's token, I am getting the result that I was getting before. I tried both searches in the same computer, and none of the pages would possibly have this 21+ age range. I will update the post to show the difference in the results.

Answer (score 1):

We are struggling with a similar version of this. We are using our application token and getting very few results when we know there are many results to be returned as we can seen them using the Graph search UI. If one person submits the query using our access_token, he gets a handful of results -- I think 14. If I cut and paste the exact same URL string (same token) into my browser, I get 2 results.

Facebook says this is "works as designed" but it is not the behavior we are seeking:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/161678720693595
```

Here is the API query string

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=bevmo&type=page&limit=1000&access_token=REMOVED&fields=id,link,username,name,website,description,about,category,location
```

and what we think is an equivalent browser search:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/str/bevmo/pages-named
```

It would seem that there should be a way to reduce the user-variability and regardless, the variability seems to be unreasonably high.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Chip. That seems the same issue.
Was it working before, like mine?


Please, if you find any solutions, post them here.